# Using Awk to pass to Bash

Tags: sed, command-line, grep

*Updated no longer using sed*

I am trying to write a script that will process certain files types that have changed in a git branch.
For instance, if someone changes a file with the ".text" extension, I want to pass that file name to some sort of bash script. I also need to remove part of the file name before passing it to the bash script.

I know that if I do the following command I can get the list of git files that have changed in a branch

```
git diff --name-only master
```

Combining that with grep, I can only retrieve the files with the special extension

```
git diff --name-only master | grep .text
```

Now here is the part I cannot get to work with command line, I want to to pass in each file individually to my bash script. The below only executes echo once with all the arguments. Is this possible?

```
git diff --name-only master | grep .text | awk -F"folder-name/" '{print $2} | xargs -t echo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked sed not to print anything by default, and you don't print anything explicitly. Here's `man sed`:

```
   -n, --quiet, --silent
          suppress automatic printing of pattern space
```

If you want automatic printing of lines, remove `-n`.

Update:

Your awk attempt is missing a single quote:

```
awk -F"folder-name/" '{print $2} 
                                ^-- Here
```

If you want to call your script with only a single argument each time, you can use `xargs -n 1`. Here's `man xargs`:

```
   -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
          Use  at  most  max-args  arguments per command line.  Fewer than
          max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s  option)
          is  exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs
          will exit.
```

Comment: i updated to use awk instead of sed, please see the above new description. appreciate it